# How many Gelflings are there in the Age of Resistance?

Tags: dark-crystal, dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

How big is the Gelfling population during the events of *The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance*? Is there a breakdown by clan? Looking for answers from the creators of the show or from the supplemental books, comics etc.

Comment: Yeah I found this very unclear as well. It seemed like no more then a few dozen unique Gelflings were shown on screen at a given time. I feel like the creators left this intentionally ambiguous.